# Typoscript HMENU: get level 1 title in level 2 navigation

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to create a menu where, for mobile purposes, before all entries of level 2 there is the title of level 1. Example: my structure looks like this:

- team

  - Max
  - Sepp
- projects

  - project 1
  - project 2

now I want my navigation to look like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Team</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li><a>Max</a></li>
        <li><a>Sepp</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Projects</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li><a>Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Project 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So I need in level 2 the title of level 1. how to I access field: nav_title for the parent element?

My typoscript looks like this:

```html
temp.nav = HMENU
temp.nav {


 1 = TMENU
 1 {
      expAll = 1
        wrap = |
      noBlur = 1

        stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
        stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
            level1Title.field = nav_title//title
        }

  NO = 1
  NO {
        ... 
  }

 }

 2 = TMENU
    2 {
        expAll = 1
        stdWrap.dataWrap = <ul><li> {register:level1Title}</li>|</ul><a>Jetzt Mitglied werden</a></div>
        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            ...
        }

    }
}
```

I tried it with LOAD_REGISTER but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is the default behaviour of TYPO3 menus. You just need to set the correct wrapping. Do the wrapping where it belongs:

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
    }
    // as you have no specific wrapping all levels can be generated the same:
    2 < .1
    3 < .2
}
```

if you want specific wraps on each level you can adapt it after copying (in this example you can see where a wrapping is coming from)

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="level1">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="lev1">|</li>
        }
    }
    2 < .1
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class="level2">|</ul>
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="lev2">|</li>
    }
    3 < .2
    3 {
        wrap = <ul class="level3">|</ul>
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="lev3">|</li>
    }
}
```

.

---

**EDIT: after clarification of problem:**
working with LOADREGISTER in menus would result in a mess as the menu items are not generated inline recursive.

If you want to repeat the menuitem you should generate it in place.
Therefore you need to split the clean wrappings and use soem enhanced menu magic.

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="level1">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

        // only for menuitems which contains further pages:
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB {
            // beginning the part of the submenu
            after.cObject = TEXT
            after.cObject {
                field = nav_title // title
                wrap = <div class="dropdown-menu"><ul><li>|</li>
            }
        }
    }
    2 < .1
    2 {
        // no beginning in wrap needed as it is done at level 1
        wrap = |</ul></div>
    }
}
```

further levels need additional handling. e.g.: `2.IFSUB >` and `3.wrap = <ul>|</ul>`

Note: If you want a clean html with indentions you need to use `.noTrimWrap` and multi line values in typoscript.

Comment: I seem to have oversimplified the needed structure - I need to have a listitem with the parent name within the subnavigation ul. I edited the original entry to clarify

Comment: answer enhanced

Comment: thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed!